# Error with Nodejs Tsyringe (undefined property)

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, koa, tsyringe

I'm using tsrynge for dependency injection in my nodejs, koa application but at the moment I'm facing an issue with a dependency. I'm receiving the following error when I try to use the createPatient method of the service in the controller:

[image]

Any idea on this?

Here is my code:

patient.routes.ts

```js
import Router, { Middleware } from "@koa/router";
import { IRoutes } from "../domain/interfaces/routes/routes.interface";
import { container, inject, injectable } from "tsyringe";
import { PatientController } from "../controllers/patient.controller";

@injectable()
export class PatientRoutes implements IRoutes {
    private router: Router;

    constructor(
        @inject(PatientController) private _patientController: PatientController,
    ) {
        this.router = new Router({ prefix: "/patient" });

        this.router.get("/", this._patientController.getPatients);
        this.router.post("/", this._patientController.createPatient);
    }

    get routes(): Middleware {
        return this.router.routes();
    }
}

const patientRoutes = container.resolve(PatientRoutes);

export default patientRoutes.routes;
```

patient.controller.ts

```js
import { Context } from "koa";
import { container, inject, injectable } from "tsyringe";
import { PatientService } from "../services/patient.service";

@injectable()
export class PatientController {
    constructor(@inject(PatientService) private patientService: PatientService) { }

    public getPatients(ctx: Context): void {
        console.log(container.isRegistered(PatientService));
        ctx.body = { message: "Get all patients" };
    }

    public async createPatient(ctx: Context): Promise<void> {
        console.log(this.patientService?.createPatient());
        ctx.body = { message: "hola" };
    }
}
```

patient.service.ts

```js
import { injectable } from "tsyringe";

@injectable()
export class PatientService {
    constructor() { }

    public async createPatient(): Promise<any> {
        console.log("Service works!");
    }
}
```

container register

```js
import { container } from "tsyringe";
import { UnitOfWork } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { ClinicHistoryController } from "../controllers/clinic-history.controller";
import { PatientController } from "../controllers/patient.controller";
import { PatientService } from "../services/patient.service";
import { PatientRoutes } from "../routes/patient.routes";

export const setDependencies = () => {
    // ==============================================================
    // ===================== Controllers ============================

    container.register(ClinicHistoryController, {
        useClass: ClinicHistoryController,
    });

    container.register(PatientController, {
        useClass: PatientController,
    });

    container.register(PatientRoutes, {
        useClass: PatientRoutes,
    });

    // ==============================================================
    // ===================== Persistence ============================
    container.register("IUnitOfWork", { useClass: UnitOfWork });
    // ==============================================================
    // ===================== Services ===============================
    container.register(PatientService, {
        useClass: PatientService,
    });
    // ==============================================================
};
```

I already try everything but don't get the solution, thank you very much for the help